# The ultimate far-future fortress

Tags: technology, science-fiction, government, far-future, dystopia

In the year 4000, a single gigantic government authority controls the world.  In the dystopian capital mega-city of "X" lies their core center of activity, where the highest of ranking officials regularly operate.

Given the level of technology we might imagine for this time period, and assuming we had no major interruptions along the way, what would be the nature of this, likely enormous, building?  More specifically, what would be the design decisions made for such a building to maximize security and absolutely prevent unauthorized access?

Comment: Hi @Christopher Hoey, welcome to Worldbuilding SE! Your question lacks specifics, for example "Given the level of technology we might imagine for this time period" leaves much room for individual opinion, which makes your question impossible to answer according to our standards.

Comment: "Put all the rats in one trap, said Gandalf" -- The Two Towers (1954)

Comment: Putting all one's eggs in one basket was a bad idea in 4000 BCE and will still be a bad idea in 4000 CE. A "government authority" does not need to operate from one building, and most certainly will not. (P.S. The word "fortress" does not mean "secure government facility"; it means a large and permanent military fortification. Given that there is a single world government, I don't see why they would have such fortification; not to mention that static military fortification went the way of the dinosaurs at the beginning of the 20th century.)

Comment: Basically *any* security can be bypassed by bribery, blackmail, intimidation or conning of individuals who work there.

Comment: In the USA there used to be 2 very important buildings, one serving as a sort of backup from another. And then along came a hijacked plane and we found out how bad of an idea it can be to rely too much on a single location. This is the same reason why building one death star instead of hundreds, if not thousands of smaller ships is a dumb idea. What's stopping a suicidal pilot that became one of the terrorist rebels from crashing an airbus into your fortress at full speed?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback and I will apply it for future questions.  I'd just like to point out that in more 'campy' fiction, eggs-in-one-basket is a common trope, but it's my fault for not being more specific. I was more interested in what technology would allow for fortification and security in this time period, which I now understand is too open-ended.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Limahuli]

[source](https://www.hawaiimagazine.com/why-limahuli-garden-and-preserve-is-a-must-visit-for-more-than-just-plant-lovers/)

What is "unauthorized access"?  How could people do things they should not do?  How could they even have the idea?  These impossible things you speak of are like a riddle.  They are hard for us to imagine.

And so let us put them from our minds.  Come and let me show you the spinach!

Comment: Bad answer to an unclear question. Do you think this is helpful?

Comment: @o.m. - I was actually very very pleased with this answer.  But if you are not, I have some other ones you could look at instead.

Comment: Requesting clarification or challenging the question is usually done in comments. I've been guilty of putting frame challenges into answers myself, but not combined with spinach.

Comment: @o.m. - I have some left over if you want to use it.